# Solution for Firefox user disabling cookies and thus localStorage - polyfill not possible

Tags: javascript, firefox, local-storage

After a complaint from one of our users and running some tests it appears Firefox 15 and 16 (and probably older version) make it so if you disable cookies you also disable localStorage. You can't even create a polyfill for it as whenever you try to access `window.localStorage` you get `Error: The operation is insecure.`

Throwing a try catch will let you check to see if it's disabled but won't let you replace the variable with your own solution. The following quick polyfill will not work because FF ignores setting the variable and will throw the same error when trying to access it:

```
try{
       window.localStorage;
}catch(err){
        window.localStorage = {
              getItem: function(k){
                   return this.k;
              },
              setItem: function(k,v){
                   this.k = v;
              }
        };
}
```

The only solution seems to be move the "fake" localStorage to another variable but this would be annoying as we have lots of code and a js lib that rely on accessing this variable. Any solutions?

**Edit:** It is not optimal to just pop up an alert to tell the users that cookies are required. If visitors just want to view the site and not signup then they truly don't need cookies. But being a backbone.js application and passing around a lot of data, we do store stuff in localStorage quite a bit.

Comment: If you can check if it's disabled, just pop an alert or something telling them that they need to enable cookies for your site.

Comment: Thanks MrObrian, I did that and am injecting a div with the message but would be optimal for the localStorage to just work as a key/value store that didn't persist, since that's what the user wants.

Comment: "but would be optimal for the localStorage to just work as a key/value store that didn't persist"

why not just use a simple js array in this case?

Comment: @S.C. The polyfill datatype is not the issue. I could use the above code I wrote as a data store I just can't use the variable window.localStorage meaning I would have to rewrite parts of my platform and a js localStorage library just to account for this one scenario so that users can truly use my platform without cookies enabled.

Comment: Your best bet may be to break your dependency on local storage. The reason I say this is some websites don't support it. I would recommend refactoring your application. instead of assigning it to an array, I would do what I could to make everything point to a function which handles data persistence and data retrieval. That way, the rest of your program doesn't have to care how/where that data is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Since `localStorage` is a reserved variable, you have no other sane option than using a wrapper with a different name. Wrap your own code and the real localStorage under this variable and replace `localStorage` with the name of your wrapper. Annoying, but less annoying than losing changes.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) Take advantage of lexical scoping and how lookups work... for example, if your code is running in a closure, then inside that closure you can run the following:

```
var localStorage = window.localStorage || {... polyfill here...};
```

Then within your code just use localStorage instead of the fully qualified window.localStorage.  The advantage here is just the way lexical variable lookups work it will find your more "closely" scoped version rather than the global.  PS... you should probably be running in a closure anyways so this should be possible.

2) just variable rename, similar to the inverse of what people do to remove vendor prefixes.

```
window.pLocalStorage = window.localStorage || {... polyfill here...};
```

Then just change your code to use pLocalStorage instead of localStorage... if their browser supports it, then it will use the native, otherwise the polyfill.

Comment: Nick, to restate the issue I wrote in the original question: "You can't even create a polyfill for it as whenever you try to access window.localStorage you get Error: The operation is insecure."  You cannot even reference this variable without throwing a JS error if you disable cookies.

Comment: Mauvis... couldn't get that error to occur textually on the Mac version.  That said the second options would work with some mods to play nicely with the try catch you had in your question...

try{
       window.pLocalStorage = window.localStorage;
}catch(err){
        window.pLocalStorage = {
              getItem: function(k){
                   return this.k;
              },
              setItem: function(k,v){
                   this.k = v;
              }
        };
}

Answer (score 0):

We use this as our lib for Local storage.

```
(function (window, $, undefined) {
    var store = window.store = {};

    function deserialize(val) {
        if (!val) return null;
        var obj = $.parseJSON(val);
        return obj;
    };

    function processRequest(loc, key, value) {
        var obj;
        // if value is not specified at all assume we are doing a get.
        if (value === undefined) {
            // GET
            obj = loc.getItem(key);
            return deserialize(value);
        } else {
            // SET
            loc.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
        }
    }

    store.Local = function(key, value) {
        return processRequest(window.localStorage, key, value);
    };

    store.Session = function(key, value) {
        return processRequest(window.sessionStorage, key, value);
    };
} (window, jQuery));
```

You could easily add some testing code to fallback on a non-persistent array.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you would have to use this to get set you'r "localStorage" stuff and not the real localStorage